# What type of clothing is considered to be the "royal touch" dress code?

Tags: dress-code

I am invited to a dinner with people who work in an embassy. It is a kind of special dinner for celebration of *Belgian King’s day* and on the invitation is was written: **dress code: royal touch**.

What type of clothing is that? I was not able to "google-search" it.

Comment: I think you need to go back ask them, is it black tie or white tie which are the two main types of formal.

Comment: I fail to see what this has to do with working conditions - it appears to be off-topic to me.

Comment: sure it is not with event directly under a working condition, but since there will be people from work, it can be considered as a work-related event, cannot? According to my experience, people who work in embassies consider these dinners(events) more or less as one part of their work.

Comment: Although the question seems to be marginally on-topic, it seems to be still on-topic, while the [Etiquette](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29783/etiquette) proposal is not yet beta.

Comment: @bytebuster just because it's not on topic elsewhere doesn't mean it's on-topic here (and similarly being on topic elsewhere doesn't necessarily make things off topic here)

Comment: I also don't think this is really a "thing". It's probably someone trying to be cute while implying "dress fancy". I don't think anyone but their secretary can answer this.

Comment: @Rarity Sure it is not that important, no one will execute me if I will have a red tie. I am not asking how should I dress for the dinner. The question is: how the royal touch dress code looks like? I was not able to find the info on the internet. When I find something I do not know I like to know. Since dress code as a topic in general belongs to workplace environment I though that someone here can know the answer.

Comment: I agree that this is not off-topic. Dress code is very much a part of the workplace, and even if this question is not about a work-related event, it should still be on-topic because its a question about dress code, not an event. I wouldn't close a question as off-topic just because someone was asking what "business casual" was for a social event instead of an interview, and wouldn't close a question that asked what the dress code "Penguins" meant for an interview. This question is about a dress code, not about an event, and I view dress code questions as on-topic for this site.

Comment: It really is just someone trying to be cute. The last place I worked at had a Christmas Party with a Hollywood theme and they marked the dress code as "Red-Carpet Chic" or something stupid and meaningless like that. As everyone else has said, just ask.

Comment: See discussion here: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/528/325

Comment: Maybe this could be more generalized like "what to do when you don't understand the dress code?"

Comment: FYI Official embassy functions have themes not dress codes.  They should be considered formal affairs unless the theme dictates otherwise like a hoe-down.  Attendees are still expected to dress up!  So just because you have hoe down does not mean that torn jeans and a plaid shirt is acceptable.  It should be a high quality costume rather than what you would actually wear to a hoe-down.

Comment: @MasterPJ: find pictures from last year.

Comment: @GregMcNulty Oooor, I will provide pictures from today's dinner :)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Why is this question still closed?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't know off-hand.  It hasn't been edited in the 2.5 years since it was closed.  It was discussed on meta and apparently some people thought it should be reopened, but they didn't must enough votes.  Others thought it should be closed. Those reopen votes have expired but could be recast.  Bring it up on meta if you'd like to get the community to act on this.

Comment: As a LARP'er, I would appear using a horned helmet, fur cloak, bare chest and a bag full of skulls of my enemies. They didn't specify _which_ royalty you should use as a reference...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there is no dress code called the "Royal Touch", and it's likely they are just trying to have some fun with their choice of words.

I have heard that phrase used when talking about the [Royal Wedding](https://web.archive.org/web/20130114122630/http://www.officialroyalwedding2011.org/) or ["Royal Touch Wedding Dresses"](https://web.archive.org/web/20121004121637/http://www.officialroyalwedding2011.org/blog/2011/July/22/The-Duchess-of-Cambridge-s-wedding-dress-to-go-on-display-at-Buckingham-Palace-this-summer), so it is possible they are trying to tell you to dress as nice as you would for if you were visiting royalty, going to a wedding, or going to a royal wedding.

Personally, I would just ask them to clarify as I've never heard of a dress code called the "Royal Touch" before (neither has Google), so it would not be unreasonable to ask for clarification.

Comment: You were right, there is no dress code as "Royal Touch". What they meant this time (and cannot be probably apply in general) is to dress kind of nice (not formal) with possible royal accessories. _for women:diademe, some things for the hair, wearing pearls, gloves,false pearl...men:scaf, hat, walking stick, bow-tie_ It was an initiative to make the dinner a little bit different from others.

Comment: @MasterPJ Thanks, I was hoping you'd share what that actually meant when you found out :)